# How to replicate a SCH_S, SCH_M deadlock

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design, database-deadlocks

I have a large migration script (about 2000 lines) that fails because of a deadlock on some metadata, and the lock types are SCH_S and SCH_M according to some xEvents data I've captured on it. The script is quite complicated, so I'm trying to recreate the same scenario using minimal scripting, so I can investigate it further. One difference between my scenario and some of the ones I've found online is that my migration script is being executed in a single process, as opposed to many examples online which use one window to make some schema changes and another window to query.

The following script is a little messy, but is my attempt at recreating the issue, but it doesn't work.

```sql
SET NOEXEC OFF;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.testfunc;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.test;

-- Create some objects.
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE test
(
    testid INT
);
GO
IF @@error <> 0
   AND @@trancount > 0
    SET NOEXEC ON;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION testfunc
()
RETURNS INT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
    (
        SELECT 2 * SUM(testid) FROM dbo.test
    );
END;
GO
IF @@error <> 0
   AND @@trancount > 0
    SET NOEXEC ON;
GO
IF @@error <> 0
   AND @@trancount > 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
ELSE IF @@trancount > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

GO

-- Try to induce a SCH_S x SCH_M deadlock.
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
GO
IF @@error <> 0
   AND @@trancount > 0
    SET NOEXEC ON;
GO
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.testfunc
()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
    (
        SELECT 2 * SUM(testid) FROM dbo.test
    );
END;
GO
EXECUTE sp_lock
IF @@error <> 0
   AND @@trancount > 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.test ADD teststring VARCHAR(12) NULL;
GO
IF @@error <> 0
   AND @@trancount > 0
    SET NOEXEC ON;
GO
SELECT TOP (1)
       testid
FROM test;
GO
EXECUTE sp_lock
go
ALTER FUNCTION testfunc
()
RETURNS INT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 testid FROM dbo.test ORDER BY testid DESC
    );
END;
GO
EXECUTE sp_lock
IF @@error <> 0
   AND @@trancount > 0
    SET NOEXEC ON;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.test ADD test_bit BIT NULL;
GO
EXECUTE sp_lock
IF @@error <> 0
   AND @@trancount > 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
ELSE IF @@trancount > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

Can someone help me recreate this kind of scenario in single process?

Here is the deadlock xml report:

```xml
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process1fbf61b8ca8" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="process1fbf61b8ca8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="METADATA: database_id = 5 USER_TYPE(user_type_id = 264), lockPartitionId = 11" waittime="2517" ownerId="46927562" transactionname="@OptionIDs" lasttranstarted="2020-01-16T13:03:44.790" XDES="0x1fb0b790490" lockMode="Sch-S" schedulerid="12" kpid="20032" status="suspended" spid="63" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2020-01-16T13:03:44.787" lastbatchcompleted="2020-01-16T13:03:44.783" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.783" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query" hostname="userhost" hostpid="11492" loginname="CORP\user" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="46926609" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671287392" clientoption2="390200">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="unknown" line="39" stmtstart="-1" sqlhandle="0x0300050048c3ee382a43d70044ab000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="66" stmtstart="-1" sqlhandle="0x010005009a7e7609c0be4a35fb01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf_GetRawPOLineDataRelatedToOption]
(
    @CommunityID INT,
    @FloorPlanID INT,
    @OptionID INT,
    @RelatedIncludedOptionIDToRemove INT
)
RETURNS @ReturnData TABLE
(
    [POTemplateID] INT NOT NULL,
    [POTemplateItemID] INT NOT NULL,
    [POTemplateItemQuantityTypeID] INT NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] DECIMAL(12, 5) NULL,
    [FloorPlanQuantityTypeID] INT NULL,
    [DynamicQuantityPercentage] INT NULL,
    [QuantityForFlooringMaterialTypeID] INT NULL,
    [HomesiteQuantityTypeID] INT NULL
)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DependencyData dbo.DependencyDataKeyValueTable;
    DECLARE @POTemplateDependencyFilterData dbo.DependencyFilterKeyValueTable;
    DECLARE @POTemplateItemDependencyFilterData dbo.DependencyFilterKeyValueTable;
    DECLARE @POTemplateIDs dbo.IndexedIntTable;

    /*
     *  Get the default dependency data for this floor plan in this community.
     */
    INSERT INTO @DependencyData
    SELECT [Key],
           [Value]
    FROM dbo.    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf_GetRawPOLineDataRelatedToOption]
(
    @CommunityID INT,
    @FloorPlanID INT,
    @OptionID INT,
    @RelatedIncludedOptionIDToRemove INT
)
RETURNS @ReturnData TABLE
(
    [POTemplateID] INT NOT NULL,
    [POTemplateItemID] INT NOT NULL,
    [POTemplateItemQuantityTypeID] INT NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] DECIMAL(12, 5) NULL,
    [FloorPlanQuantityTypeID] INT NULL,
    [DynamicQuantityPercentage] INT NULL,
    [QuantityForFlooringMaterialTypeID] INT NULL,
    [HomesiteQuantityTypeID] INT NULL
)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DependencyData dbo.DependencyDataKeyValueTable;
    DECLARE @POTemplateDependencyFilterData dbo.DependencyFilterKeyValueTable;
    DECLARE @POTemplateItemDependencyFilterData dbo.DependencyFilterKeyValueTable;
    DECLARE @POTemplateIDs dbo.IndexedIntTable;

    /*
     *  Get the default dependency data for this floor plan in this community.
     */
    INSERT INTO @DependencyData
    SELECT [Key],
           [Value]
    FROM dbo   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <metadatalock subresource="USER_TYPE" classid="user_type_id = 264" dbid="5" lockPartition="11" id="lock1fb8a56df00" mode="Sch-M">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process1fbf61b8ca8" mode="Sch-M" />
    <owner id="process1fbf61b8ca8" mode="Sch-S" requestType="wait" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process1fbf61b8ca8" mode="Sch-S" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </metadatalock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

[image: deadlockgraph]

Comment: You can't create a deadlock with a single session.

Comment: You can create a deadlock in a single process, but not in any normal way. A deadlock between threads for a single statemen *is* possible, but isn't normally reproducible..

Comment: Do you have deadlock graphs and XML for the deadlocks that are happening? If not, I recommend a simple deadlock monitor in extended events. This SQL statement will create one: `CREATE EVENT SESSION [Deadlock_Graphs] ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.xml_deadlock_report
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'Deadlock_Graphs',max_file_size=(20))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=ON)`

Comment: You will have to add line breaks before `ADD EVENT`, `ADD TARGEt`, and `WITH`

Comment: I'll add the deadlock xml report..

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft You can do in this case. It is a known issue with creating UDTs and then referencing them as discussed here https://sqlperformance.com/2013/11/t-sql-queries/single-tx-deadlock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone help me recreate this kind of scenario in single process?

There is a simple demo of this issue [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/52900/3690).

```
BEGIN TRAN

go

CREATE TYPE dbo.OptionIDs AS TABLE( OptionID INT PRIMARY KEY )

go

DECLARE @OptionIDs dbo.OptionIDs;

go

ROLLBACK
```

It is certainly unusual to have a deadlock involving a single process and single resource.

The resource is `metadatalock subresource="USER_TYPE" classid="user_type_id = 264"`

The session already holds a `SCH-M` metadata lock on a user defined type (probably as you created it earlier in the script) and this blocks an attempt to get a `SCH-S` lock on the same object by the same session later.

The transaction name shown in the deadlock graph is `@OptionIDs` - this is an **internal** system transaction that writes to the `tempdb` transaction log when creating the instance of the table type corresponding with the `DECLARE @OptionIDs` above. This is a separate transaction from the surrounding user transaction which is why the session is unexpectedly unable to get a `SCH-S` lock despite already holding the `SCH-M` lock.

This is blogged about by Aaron Bertrand [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/11/t-sql-queries/single-tx-deadlock)

Comment: Thank you! My script did in fact create a user-defined type, and then try to use it later in a stored proc. When I created the type in its own transaction, the rest of the script worked perfectly.